# finding visited links in a jetpack extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there way in jetpack(mozilla's extension development framework) , to find the the visited links in a page?

BTW: jquery's a:visited works in firebug , but not in jetpack. i'm guessing
it's part of jetpack's security.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jetpack, but wether a link is marked as visited or not is a browsers decision depending on the individual history of the user. By clearing your history all links will become unvisited.
So, the answer to your questions depends on the time when jetpack interacts, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read whether a particular link is selected from JavaScript, you can only do it indirectly, using a Selector. Consequently `a:visited` is not supported by jQuery/Sizzle; if it works for you, that's only because jQuery is farming off the selector to the browser's native `querySelectorAll` interface; on older browsers that don't support Selectors-API Level 1, it won't work.

You can try `document.querySelectorAll('a:visited')` directly to see whether the environment allows history reading. The spec [allows](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#privacy) a browser to block it, and certainly IE does; I don't know about JetPack.

The nasty hack that was used to snoop history previously, which might still be applicable, is to add a rule to the stylesheet targeting visited links and see if the element has been matched by looking at its `currentStyle`/`getComputedStyle` (`.css` in jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

Except the solution suggested by @bobince has been eliminated as a security issue in the latest versions of Firefox.